# Adding two matrices of different order in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new on matlab. I read an image of order 42 X 25. I took derivative along x-axis and y axis of that image. 
when I take derivative along x-axis the order of image becomes 42 X 24 and when I take along Y-axis it becomes 41 X 25.

NOW I want to add these two matrices. but they are of different orders so I cant. But if I append column of zeros in derivative of image along x-axis and row of zeros in derivative of image along y-axis. this thing can make the matrices of same order.

```
I = imread('abc.jpg');

BW=im2bw(I,graythresh(I));

I_derived_x = diff(BW, 1, 2);
I_derived_y = diff(BW, 1, 1);
```

Now i want to do

```
SUM = I_derived_x + I_derived_y
```

so kindly help me in making the order of these two matrices. thanks in advance

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190411/zero-padding-in-matlab) for several solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By researching on [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/padarray.html), I found the solution which I was seeking for. This is how to add row/column of zeros in your matrix.

```
I_derived_x = padarray(I_derived_x,[0 1],0,'post'); 
I_derived_y = padarray(I_derived_y,[1 0],0,'post');
```

Here in function first argument is matrix, second is order means I want to add one more column and no row in `I_derived_x` matrix, third argument means how I want to fill it, like in my case I want it to be filled with zeros and last argument specifies the direction of newly added row/column, As I want it at the end of my matrix so I used `post` here.

Answer (score 1):

Using `diff` for calculating derivatives is usefull, but you'll have to understand it: `diff` essentially calculates the forward finite differences; thus it makes sense that you only get `N-1` derivative values out of `N` points.

You can solve it with zero padding (which screws up your edges)

OR

Use central finite differences for points in the middle of the range and forward/backward finite differences for points on the edge.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

EDIT:In your case, this will resolve into:

```
I_derived_x = 0.5*[BW(:,2)-BW(:,1)  ,  0.5*(BW(:,3:end)-BW(:,1:end-2))  ,  BW(:,2)-BW(:,1)];
I_derived_y = 0.5*[BW(2,:)-BW(1,:)  ;  0.5*(BW(3:end,:)-BW(1:end-2,:))  ;  BW(2,:)-BW(1,:)];
```

which gives you the derivatives on the same grid as `BW`. This easily allows taking the sum of them as you wanted

```
SUM = I_derived_x + I_derived_y
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the function `diffs` to solve exactly this problem. It performs the same operation as `diff`, but it pads the output with `NaN` so that it is the same size as the input. You could replace the call to `NaN` with a call to `zeros` if you didn't want `NaN` in your output.

Note that this doesn't work with higher dimensional arrays (i.e. dimension greater than 2).

```
function d = diffs(x,n,dim)
%"DIFF Difference the columns/rows of a matrix and return a result the same"
%"size as the original"

    if nargin < 2
        n = 1;
    end
    if nargin < 3
        dim = 1;
    end

    if dim == 2
        x = transpose(x);
    end

    k = size(x,2);
    d = [NaN(n,k); diff(x,n)];

    if dim == 2
        d = transpose(d);
    end

end
```

You can now use your original code, with the call to `diff` replaced with a call to `diffs`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's annoying.

- As suggested you can use zero padding - but I would then use the 3 point derivative.
- Or you can interpolate as I would locate the derivatives at 1/2 between the numbers it should be easy to write a `interp2` command. You need to decide if you'd like to extrapolate the border - or just leave it nan.