# Adding Padding to Image - Matlab

Tags: matlab, padding

I have a small image that is `89x56px` in size and is RGB.

I'm trying to add padding around the image until both (x,y) are greater than 64px.

I've tried this by reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190411/zero-padding-a-matrix): but with no luck:

```
  img = subImage{1};              %small image 89x56
  new(size(subImage{1},1),64)=0;  %zero matrix for padding
  size(new);
  merged = img;                   %also tried adding img to new
  imshow(merged)
```

Ideally I would like even padding each side of the image. eg 64 - 56 = 8; so 4 columns of 0 each side (or just 8 on the end if it's too difficult.)

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be greater than or equal to 64px?

Comment: Yes it should. Well spotted :D Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have `imshow`, you should have [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/padarray.html), too:

```
pad = [64 64 0] - size(img);
pad(pad<0) = 0;
merged = padarray(img, floor(pad./2));
```

Comment: Ah cool. I literally just read about padarray. Very handy function. Thanks for perfect answer :D

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
limit = 64; %%// Padding limit

[sz1 sz2 C] = size(img);
ad1 = round((limit - min([sz1 sz2]))/2);
img1 = uint8(zeros(sz1+2*ad1,sz2+2*ad1,3));
img1(ad1:ad1+sz1-1,ad1:ad1+sz2-1,:) = img;

figure,imshow(img1)
```

The code assumes that you want to pad equally on left and right and at top and bottom.

Comment: This is nice to know. Especially for equal padding. Thanks for posting (: